# Switching scenes in Unity C# after a short delay without the use of update

Tags: 2d, scene, unity-game-engine, collider

Title is self explanatory. I'm trying to switch scenes after a short delay WITHOUT using the update() function. The trigger is a collision between two objects which I have working, I also understand how to switch scenes. It is the delay after the collision which I am struggling with.

I am very new to Unity, any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Unity supports using [Coroutines](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html), which will help with calling the LoadScene function after a delay.

An example of this is as follows:

```
void OnCollisionEnter()
{
    StartCoroutine("LoadLevelWithDelay");
}

IEnumarator LoadLevelWithDelay()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2.0f);

    LoadScene(scene);
}
```

This code isn't fully working since it's just an example, but this is how you could do it. Just create a function of type IEnumerator that waits for however long you want before continuing, and load the scene when it continues.